# Solving ODE with Simulink in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, solver, ode, differential-equations

I need to solve this ODE using Simulink and I don't know how to make it.
I only know how to do it using ODE solvers.

```
y'' - y' - 2y = e^(3x)

y(0)=1, y'(0)=2.
```

I rewrote the equation obtaining an ODEs:

```
y' = f(x,y)

y(x0) = y0

y'1 = y2

y2= e^(3*x) + y' + 2y
```

Using ODE solver.

If someone can help me to solve this using a Simulink Model I would appreciate it.

I know how to solve it in Matlab using ODE solvers as ode23 and ode23s but I don't know how to do it using a Simulink Model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: love this typo `using smiling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you solve it in closed form?  Looks doable to me.  I advise anyone to have the answer in hand if possible before you start a numerical solution.

Here's what I get.  Check me:

```
y(x) = e^(-x)*(8e^3x + 3e^4x + 1)/12
```

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+-+y%27+-+2y+%3D+e%5E%283x%29%2C++y%280%29+%3D+1%2C+y%27%280%29+%3D2) says this is correct.

(Note: Trouble for large values of x - this response will grow at e^3x rate.)

You need to express this as a set of coupled first order ODEs.

```
y' = z

z' = z + 2y + e^(3x)
```

Boundary conditions become:

```
y(0) = 1
z(0) = 2
```

Comment: The initial condition for `y` is `y(0)=1` not `y(0)=0`. Upvoted though.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I misread it.  I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the equation yourself term by term in Simulink and add the initial conditions to the integrators by double clicking and setting the corresponding field.

So a quick implementation looks like

[image]

I assumed that your x is a time-like quantity hence I placed a ramp function. Clock etc. would also do.

Alternatively you can form the state space system or the transfer function with explicitly taking the initial conditions into account.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. I also need to scope it, where should i put the scope?

Comment: @jorreto depends on what younwould like to see. You can connect one to the y branch which is the typical choice when a solution is mentioned.